# Are those sentences with 'solution to' correct?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-patterns

1. One **solution to solving** unemployment problems is help from governments.
2. One **solution to solve** unemployment problems is help from governments.

Thank you very much for your time and answers.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you trying to solve the problem of unemployment, or are you trying to solve the problem of finding a solution to the problem of unemployment?

Comment: I'm going to solve the problem of unemployment, sir.

Comment: As @Caius points out, there is an unfortunate redundancy in 'one solution to solving' ... etc. 'Is A or B less worse?' questions need improving.

Answer (score 1):

> Are those sentences with 'solution to' correct?

Not from my perspective as a native speaker, no

---

From your comment that you're trying to directly solve the problem the sentence mentions, I'd connect the use of "solution" directly to the use of "problem"..

- One solution to unemployment problems is help from governments.
- One solution to the problem of unemployment, is help from governments.

..or if you want to connect "solve" to the problem, drop the use of "solution"..

- One method of solving unemployment problems is help from governments.
- One way to solve unemployment problems is help from governments.

..rather than a sentence construct that causes the reading user to closely associate "solution" with "solve" - because solving is "providing a solution" it doesn't make sense to "solve a solution".

If you want to outline that the solution is one of many, add some more wording to distance "solution" from "solve", and more clearly create a "set of problems that are solved" so you can talk about one of the solutions:

- One solution, in the typical set of ways we solve unemployment problems, is help from governments [in the form of..]

Comment: Hello, Caius. OP asks whether their two suggestions are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two explanations for the construct. Both depend on ellipsis. My suggestions for the omitted material are shown {so}.

One solution to {the question of} solving unemployment problems is help from governments.

One solution to {the} solving {of} unemployment problems is help from governments.

> Ellipsis = a situation in which words are left out of a sentence but the sentence can still be understood
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ellipsis)

Comment: And is there any supporting evidence that this particular relict is considered acceptable? After all, 'One solution to [the present predicament, the need to] solve unemployment problems[,] is help from governments' can be partially deleted to leave (2). // Note that this is not a labelling as incorrect, it is an appeal for the regulation supporting evidence. Ngram results should work well.